# How to play rtmp audio using AudioToolbox in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio, audio-streaming, rtmp

i am a start up developer in streaming section. how can play the below data in AudioToolbox without other lib

My rtmp wowza server configuration
aac lc, 44100Hz, 128kbps

my rtmp lib audio out is like this
< af0100e4 9dfefc12 084a6159 ee8e9547 d1dba750 8f3e40f1 1115d83d 1c4c0ce6 520c5cbe 92459167 95a28427 53776ca2 acdf2686 5645665e 0594bf36 8129d270 144d4cdc e4a0f188 05f5be3e 37061789 3715b4f9 07303ea8 377f1096 6e564127 fe1d7fc2 e9b96499 5827dc2a ea3235e3 b50832c4 9f148dab fdf44a0a 9db93104 9c4b1982 300a361e bf6a6744 91afb323 858a48b2 2ba2dbed 9f281015 6a2250cc 08169686 30b538cd 42084249 bb089010 442523c7 b9ad13c3 88ab5580 63ab0864 993c95fc 5128e826 e8f95a29 28520888 d8253bac 975888ae 31600280 1850ac8e 2fc94400 a970bd10 4b099020 d6548a21 04f69abc 97f63b2b aee5b393 1289aa2d 4b5acc1e 55864870 cf0abd7a e3c05391 610a7eef adca4d4d 99ce4624 5270e310 7ef489d8 4a02fb4a cc1d649f 6ba81553 825f6901 4e958a46 55e252ca 501668a0 38140601 8905340c d4dc741d b9d61e79 e364e52a 52b750e7 49967919 74892e24 eabce892 50455cc0 a128f4db b48a1bfa 5a183885 a40735a2 0a00563a 0901b32c 50000030 00d2c00e 00e61457 1c05000c 65b7bf1e ff524219 48430606 024c0932 3fe7bc4f 7e50e2ac 8199e92f 12f6acc9 f3f98c88 184c05ad db69908a 1bcf6000 00000000 00020002 6929d029 83921bb3 b1a41567 e2af9efd 258d988c b2b972ff 25a98e95 672723be a7a18700 00b5c000 e0 >

next pack

< af01010c d8afe780 a0842077 ddc78d66 cf68c8a4 ae39a929 a62a76d5 e66eb60d 43262b8c b8be5911 09316667 6146dee2 3c4943a0 77471011 fa427acd 7630fffe d15eb363 37d8090c e48f0a67 2f86621d 87555a42 dd570b6c 8801d51d 0ed5f52a 201dfbb9 d2d683d9 ae1e45d6 becb986f 0beb4cfe 4ea536dc fdbfff3b ab9b3200 093e4606 72512e92 290963f2 b8f92458 7a856444 2201864a ea894b85 81d2bade 46c2320a 3c4894ac 0da4abae a1196ea9 27104472 043cacec f1f59f68 ff4da25c 055c0fa9 f7c56412 22844624 e2331144 02a64fef c920a458 7b54a4a0 b7fa9420 70556087 a0916aa8 9005f2df 8a24f013 013544f8 1a187e43 81265515 5cc32e37 2b1f064b 4fb89e97 d3588f3b 9a555779 fcf91392 a506a49d 97531247 e9722147 fe1e9849 e3941f67 a8932390 84a2509d 6b8eb481 418ff09c 6976b10f 179321f4 8cb20e8e 9607741c 9191b148 04642100 8885b77a 16a60f14 5626a24f f71fa657 50494594 4990e4f0 116148c6 813a2894 95923422 53c24dc0 adc7fedf c1cacb24 b85d0d9d 0f2f8889 892e87fe c4011894 c513146c 783c0c36 2b2cd113 0cf215a7 92588960 a0d09269 aceaf211 98418693 d9274af5 bfefcc8b b1457608 9359c13d 2ba488b1 d03eb1ea d24844ae 9d8beb76 6948005f 4ab02a60 6257cf78 f54f427c b7cd64bc d64562d7 13a14984 1f569383 6f9bdc2d d2539e65 8313544d fc465d36 760fb5cc 737f1a3d 564558df ba3aea0f 616b3e49 a738fdfa bb30d2d8 95275455 72243e9a 60731f14 12f4d513 c8b351af a0c53ab7 cd8a84f8 0de76483 c49695d7 2ca0ce70 >

please help me...

Comment: Have you tried Audio File Stream Services? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162-CH1-SW1

Comment: Hi Sboot, Thx for your answer. But i my question is how to play this RTMP audio package. this package contain a audio header, i don't know header details and how to split the original audio data from this package.